# Closing lightbox sometimes fires faster than onblur() on input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running this code `on blur()` on an input. It works great, as long as you don't click on anything that takes you to a different page or closes the lightbox (div in an overlay) where the ajax function and input was loaded from, since there is a chance that the ajax script will be aborted. I get that it may be hard to make sure that the content is saved `on blur()` if you close the browser window, but is there any way I can wait until the ajax request (and any link click) is finished before I close the lightbox (or move on to a different page)?

I guess another option would be to have `on input()` instead/as well as `on blur()`, but then I get a lot of ajax requests and need to start throttling right? My lightbox plugin (fancybox) has an event called `beforeClose`, can I run something in there that checks if the ajax request was sent?

Please let me know if I'm thinking about this the wrong way. I know that async false is not really recommended, but maybe what I need?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "?a=ajax",
    data: { value: $self.val() },
    error: handleError
}).done(function(data) {
    if( data == "0" )
    {
        // no success
    }
    else
    {
        // success
    }
});
```